# where can i find c++ std API's - for example api for std::list

Tags: c++, std, stdlist

I'm doing some homework for school, and I would like to study the api for std::list, as i'm supposed to implement one of my own.
I'd like to implement a similar interface to that of std, so that i may use my own list comfortably later.

Thanks.

Comment: cppreference.com is my favourite these days. Replicating the interface of `std::list` will be challenging, I feel.

Comment: any decent IDE with an autocomplete feature or `vim` with something like `youcompleteme` will do the trick

Comment: @user2485710: autocomplete will not help you replicate an API. It generally doesn't give you much information about what a function actually _does_, after all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the complete list of member functions and operators at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) (as also pointed out by @Rook)

But I also think this is not easy, and for sure not for a C++ beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [these offline man pages for STL](https://github.com/jeaye/stdman).